# Django models for non user-created tables

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am working on a project using veekun's pokedex sqlite database, and using it in a django project.

They have many tables including encounter rates, pokemons, types, etc. Most of these the user will not need to interact with (really only needs to read from database, not create, update, or delete).

Is it worth it to create models based off the database either manually or through `inspectdb`? Will I see any performance boost?

I am new to django so I may be misunderstanding the purpose of models here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can be useful to be able to get the benefits of the Django ORM such as [QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/) and be able to have the admin interface if required. I have only needed to do this once before and found it okay following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/legacy-databases/

You may or may not observe any performance boosts depending upon how you would construct the queries manually.

It should be noted that Django does not support [cross database migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#cross-database-relations) if you were planning on relating the models. If you need this it would have to be done manually.

Comment: I wanted to integrate it with the default django database. Is that not advised/not possible?

Comment: It is possible but you wont be able to use a `ForeignKey`. What you can do is store the `pk` of the record from the pokedex database into an appropriate field in your Django managed database. You when then need two queries to obtain what you are after e.g. if you are after all related pokemon with the name containing 'a' ignoring case `DjangoModel.objects.filter(pk_pokedex__in=PokedexModel.objects.filter(pokeman_name__icontains='a'))`

Comment: Oh, this database has a lot of ForeignKey's it may be best to leave it alone then, or to recreate it manually.

Comment: I'm going to mark yours as the answer. Its not the answer I wanted, but you did accurately answer my question. Its unfortunate that it will not work out the way I wanted.